# How to list posts in specific category [ionic & angularjs]

Tags: android, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework

I am creating a hybrid android app using wordpress json api, ionic and angularjs.
I am stuck at just one thing : I am unable to list the posts in a particular category.I got the list of categories but unable to pass some parameters.
Here's the code

controller.js

```
.controller('CatsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  // You can change this url to experiment with other endpoints
  var categoriesApi = 'http://shayarihunt.com/wp-    json/taxonomies/category/terms?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';

  // This should go in a service so we can reuse it
   $http.jsonp( categoriesApi, {cache:true} ).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.categories = data;
     console.log( data );
     }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log( 'Post load error.' );
 });

})

.controller('CatsPostsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  // You can change this url to experiment with other endpoints
   var postsApi = 'http://shayarihunt.com/wp-json/posts?filter[cat]=' + the parameter has to come here, (I dont know what!!!) + '&_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';

  // This should go in a service so we can reuse it
    $http.jsonp( postsApi, {cache:true} ).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.posts = data;
  console.log( data );
   }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log( 'Post load error.' );
    });

   })
```

The CatsCtrl display all categories but CatsPostsCtrl should display all posts in category which it doesn't.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `$stateParams` from `ui-router`. Please have a look at the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters) for more details.

Below is a demo usage. Click on the second icon to show the posts in category `hindi-shayari`. You can also find the same code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/2L5qcxtc/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ionic'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      views: {
          home: {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'CatsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('category', {
      url: '/category/:slug',
      views: {
          category: {
              templateUrl: 'category.html',
              controller: 'CatsPostsCtrl'
          }
      }
  });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
.controller('CatsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  // You can change this url to experiment with other endpoints
  var categoriesApi = 'http://shayarihunt.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';

  // This should go in a service so we can reuse it
   $http.jsonp( categoriesApi, {cache:true} ).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.posts = data;
     console.log( data );
     }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log( 'Post load error.', status, headers);
 });

})

.controller('CatsPostsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {

   console.log($stateParams);
    // You can change this url to experiment with other endpoints
   var postsApi = 'http://shayarihunt.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=' + $stateParams.slug + '&_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
    $scope.category = $stateParams.slug;
  // This should go in a service so we can reuse it
    $http.jsonp( postsApi, {cache:true} ).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.posts = data;
  console.log( data );
   }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log( 'Post load error.' );
    });

   })
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <script id="post-partial.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
                <h2 ng-bind-html="post.title"></h2>
                <p ng-bind-html="post.content"></p>
            </div>
    </script>
    <script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <!-- The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar -->
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content>
          <!-- The content of the page -->
            <!--<a ui-sref="category({slug:'hindi-shayari'})">Go to hindi-shayari category!</a>-->
            <div ng-include="'post-partial.html'"></div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    
    <script id="category.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <!-- The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar -->
      <ion-view view-title="Category">
        <ion-content>
          <!-- The content of the page -->
            <h1 ng-bind-html="category"></h1>
          <div ng-include="'post-partial.html'"></div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    
    
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">
    <ion-tab icon="ion-home" ui-sref="home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab icon="ion-navicon-round" ui-sref="category({slug:'hindi-shayari'})">
      <ion-nav-view name="category"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @awolf . But I want to display the list of categories which I am able to using {{category.name}} and the category url in the controller. Then when a user clicks on the category, it should display list of posts in that category using {{post.title}}, How is that possible, ?...thanks a ton for the answer

Comment: What categories do you have? It's a bit hard to see them in the json. Can you please write me 2 or 3 of your categories? Then I can find them in JSON.

Comment: OK, please have a look at the updated fiddle. The link list to the categories is added to home route.

Comment: thank you so much @awolf . Could you please let  me know what files to create and which one will contain which code. I'm sorry if I'm causing you trouble.Thanks in advance!!!